# including folder into jar files

Tags: java, jar, classpath

If we have a following structure

root(folder)  -> -> jarss(folder) -> com(package) -> MyClass.class

and MyJar.jar(includes jarss/com.MyClass.class) located inside **root**(folder)

How to give path of com.myclass ?

eg. `javac -cp root/MyJar.jar AnOtherClass.java`

(this is not working because there is jars folder inside the MyJar.jar file first then MyClass.class)

Comment: Java's default class loaders do not support Jar-in-Jar.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to put *.Java file in Jar? One more thing that Java doesnot support jar in jar funda.

If you want to do this, suppose you have a Jar file in which org.test.test1.Myclass.java.
that means jar file have a folder org , in which there will be a folder test and then test1 folder, test1 folder will have your class MyClass.java.

Just set the path of Jar file in your CLASSPATH like,

**set CLASSPATH=./lib/MyJAR.jar**

Then run it as,

**javac -classpath %CLASSPATH% org.test.test1.Myclass.java**

(Also look for the syntax and attributes of javac.)

I hope that this may give you some hint for the problem you are having.

Comment: i am not putting *.java files into jar i am asking how to use *.class files inside a folder which is inside a jar file.

Comment: @user460293:-just set the jar file in classpath & provide -classpath switch & use it. but if Jar consist of another jar in it. then it will not be supported by Java